# creating an xml compound document with xsl and adding prefix in the same xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

This should not be this complicated.  I have two xml files and I need to create a compound document with them.

```
<!--cars.xml -->
<cars>
   <car cid="nes201">
      <title>Straight Away</title>
      <model>Nissan</model>
      <driver>indy</driver>
   </car>
   <car cid="gda100-5">      
      <title>Quick Start</title>
      <model>General Motors</model>
      <driver>indy</driver>      
   </car>
   <car cid="gma005-2">      
      <title>Stop Blocks Laps</title>
      <model>Ford</model>
      <driver>indy</driver>     
   </car>
</cars>
<!--teams.xml -->
<teams>
   <team tid="t205">
      <title>Rodas Motorsports</title>
      <description>#1 Team in racing</description>
      <series>Indy</series>
   </team>
   <team tid="t105">
      <title>SAM Racing</title>
      <description>Top 10 over last 5 years</description>
      <series>Nascar</series>
   </team>
</teams>
```

I need to add a prefix and combined both in the result document teamscars.xml.
As follows

```
<teamsCars>
    <crs:cars>
       <crs:car cid="nes201">
          <crs:title>Straight Away</crs:title>
          <crs:model>Nissan</crs:model>
          <crs:driver>indy</crs:driver>
       </crs:car>
       <crs:car cid="gda100-5">      
          <crs:title>Quick Start</crs:title>
          <crs:model>General Motors</crs:model>
          <crs:driver>indy</crs:driver>      
       </crs:car>
       <crs:car cid="gma005-2">      
          <crs:title>Stop Blocks Laps</crs:title>
          <crs:model>Ford</crs:model>
          <crs:driver>indy</crs:driver>     
       </crs:car>
    </crs:cars>
    <tms:teams>
       <tms:team tid="t205">
          <tms:title>Rodas Motorsports</tms:title>
          <tms:description>#1 Team in racing</tms:description>
          <tms:series>Indy</tms:series>
       </tms:team>
       <tms:team tid="t105">
          <tms:title>SAM Racing</tms:title>
          <tms:description>Top 10 over last 5 years</tms:description>
          <tms:series>Nascar</tms:series>
       </tms:team>
    </tms:teams>
</teamsCars>
```

I figured out hot to add the prefix but I can only add it to one file and not copy the rest.  Hope someone shed some light, please.  Here is what I can use but missing most of it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" 
        omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
        indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">    
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="crs:{name()}" namespace="http://example.com/cars">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process two XML files, you must select one as the input to the transformation and read the other one through the `document()` function. Here 's an example where the `cars.xml` file is the file being processed and the `teams.xml` file is the "other" file:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <teamsCars>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="crs"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('teams.xml')" mode="tms"/>
    </teamsCars>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="crs">
    <xsl:element name="crs:{name()}" namespace="http://example.com/cars">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="crs"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="tms">
    <xsl:element name="tms:{name()}" namespace="http://example.com/teams">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="tms"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Assuming you have given the `document()` function the correct path to the `teams.xml` file, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<teamsCars>
  <crs:cars xmlns:crs="http://example.com/cars">
    <crs:car cid="nes201">
      <crs:title>Straight Away</crs:title>
      <crs:model>Nissan</crs:model>
      <crs:driver>indy</crs:driver>
    </crs:car>
    <crs:car cid="gda100-5">
      <crs:title>Quick Start</crs:title>
      <crs:model>General Motors</crs:model>
      <crs:driver>indy</crs:driver>
    </crs:car>
    <crs:car cid="gma005-2">
      <crs:title>Stop Blocks Laps</crs:title>
      <crs:model>Ford</crs:model>
      <crs:driver>indy</crs:driver>
    </crs:car>
  </crs:cars>
  <tms:teams xmlns:tms="http://example.com/teams">
    <tms:team tid="t205">
      <tms:title>Rodas Motorsports</tms:title>
      <tms:description>#1 Team in racing</tms:description>
      <tms:series>Indy</tms:series>
    </tms:team>
    <tms:team tid="t105">
      <tms:title>SAM Racing</tms:title>
      <tms:description>Top 10 over last 5 years</tms:description>
      <tms:series>Nascar</tms:series>
    </tms:team>
  </tms:teams>
</teamsCars>
```

Note that unlike the output in your question, this one contains namespace declarations binding the used prefixes to actual namespace URIs - as a well-formed XML document must do.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That's exactly what I needed.  i didn't think about the mode.  Was getting to the frustration mode.